# How does angular decide if a form element is pristine or dirty?

Tags: angularjs

For example, ng-required calls $isEmpty to determine if it should set ng-invalid-required, etc. What does Angular call to decide if it should set ng-dirty?

Answer (score 0):

Hope I have understood your question correctly. If not please let me know.

You can use `$setDirty();` method to `Sets the form to a dirty state.`.This method can be called to add the `ng-dirty` class and set the form to a dirty state (`ng-dirty` class).

Angular detects this by using `$dirty` property.It is a `boolean` property. If it is `True` then user has already interacted with the form.

We can use `$setPristine()` method to `Sets the form to its pristine state`.This method can be called to remove the `ng-dirty` class and set the form to its `pristine` state (`ng-pristine` class).We use this method when we want to `reuse` a form after `saving` or `resetting` it.

Angular detect this by using `$pristine` property.It is a `boolean` property. If it is `True` then user has not interacted with the form yet.

Comment: Yes, but I'm really asking about what Angular calls behind the scenes, not how I can set it myself manually.

Answer (score 0):

The dirty state indicates whether it is modified to some actions or not